# Can you play a rent card and then a double the rent card?

Tags: monopoly-deal

Can you play a rent card and charge them rent? then a double the rent card on top of it to charge additional money

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mostly. You double the amount collected in that one rent payment. Usually this is the same as collecting the rent a second time, but note that "Just Say No" would cancel the whole thing, not just the second payment, so it may be slightly different than you're thinking:

> Play immediately after a standard Rent card to double the amount of rent collected. Can also be banked as money. Bank value: 1M. (NOTE: Playing this card along with a Rent card counts as two of your three possible card plays for your turn, per Hasbro).
>
> - Playing a Just Say No card cancels both the Rent card **and** the Double the Rent card, per Hasbro.

Quoted from https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Monopoly_Deal#The_Cards_In_Detail